# Use login shell in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, terminator

I installed a fresh vm of Xubuntu 14.04 and installed the Ruby Version Manager (rvm).

While trying to install the SASS gem I get the following error:

```
$ rvm use 2.0

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I checked [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function) and used configured terminator to use a login shell:

[image: loginshell-on-terminator]

Unfortunately, after doing this new terminals won't show the prompt:

[image: terminator-not-working]

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Try using Terminal instead of Terminator.  Also, checking the website posted in your error message, you need to be sure that you ~/.bash_profile has an entry to source the RVM script noted in their explanation.  After starting Terminal, type "/bin/bash --login" then retry your original command.  This starts bash as a login shell, when finished type 'exit' and you should see logout.

Comment: After installing Terminator, I cannot duplicate your issue.  Tick the box labelled "Run a custom command instead of my shell" Then make this entry in the "Custom command" box /bin/bash --login.

Comment: @RCF-U14.04 I just tried using the default console and I get the same result. Even if I use the "/bin/bash --login" command.

Comment: @RCF-U14.04 I mean that I get the same result i.e. the cursor just blinks as if it was executing a command or infinite loop.

Comment: Let's try this approach and see if we can get some results.  Uninstall gnome-terminal "sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal" Also, Unistall Terminator,  "sudo apt-get autoremove Terminator"  Then re-install "sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal".

Comment: Are you using Virtualbox or VMware?

Comment: I'm using VMWare player. I tried uninstalling and also purged the install. No luck D:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get your Terminator to run Bash as a login shell by checking the "Run a special command instead of my shell".

1. Open Terminator
2. Right click on the window and select "preferences"
3. Go to Profiles
4. Command tab
5. Make sure you have only the "Run a special command instead of my shell" checked.
6. In the command box enter `/bin/bash --login`
7. For the option labelled "When command exits" select "Hold terminal open"
8. Close Terminator, then re-open Terminator

This should have you running Bash in a login shell.  To Verify, in Terminator enter:

```
 shopt login_shell
```

It should return "yes" and you know you are running a login shell.